# How to dlopen jemalloc dynamic library

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, dlopen, jemalloc

I am trying to `dlopen` memory allocators at runtime. 
I have no problem with `libc`, `tcmalloc` and `tbbmalloc`. But trying to `dlopen` `jemalloc` results in the following error (caught via `dlerror`) :

`/path/to/lib/libjemalloc.so: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block`

Do you have any idea of the reason for this error and hence how I could tackle this ?

Comment: I do not think those libraries are designed to be open with `dlopen`.

Comment: Seems like an issue in jemalloc version you have. In any case this is not really good idea to use dynamic library loading nether dlopen nor LoadLibrary for memory allocators. Imagine what is going to happen, when you call to a `free` function when allocator is already unloaded. Link shared libraries to the executable instead.

Comment: @SergeyA What do you mean by not "designed to be open with `dlopen`", please ?
@VictorGubin I am aware of this pitfall. I am trying to design a subsystem to be able to use multple allocation strategies within the same program. Linking sharing libraries is thus not enough and making sure to free allocated memory with the good allocator is part of the program design.

Comment: They are designed to be linked automatically through dynamic loader and become available before program starts executing.

Comment: One has to use `dlsym()` to retrieve the `calloc()`, `free()`, `malloc()` and `realloc()`  functions provided by the allocator dynamic library *and* one has to be very careful not to free or reallocate a pointer provided by one allocator with the functions of another allocator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this thanks to `jemalloc`'s GitHub repository [issue #1237](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/issues/1237).

This solution was to recompile `jemalloc` using the `--disable-initial-exec-tls` according to the [INSTALL.md](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/blob/dev/INSTALL.md), my bad.